# Reshape the dataframe including repeated columes

Tags: python, pandas

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type' : ['A', 'A', 'B'],
'Var1' : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
'Var2' : [21.0, 22.0, 23.0],
'Var3' : [np.nan, 4.0, 5.0],
'Var4' : [np.nan, 24.0, 25.0]
})
```

```
|   | Type | Var1 | Var2 | Var3 | Var4 |
|---|------|-----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|
| 0 |    A |  1.0 | 21.0 |  NaN |  NaN |
| 1 |    A |  2.0 | 22.0 |  4.0 | 24.0 |
| 2 |    B |  3.0 | 23.0 |  5.0 | 25.0 |
```

In the dataset, the `Var3` and `Var4` are the same as `Var1` and `Var2` respectively. Sometimes `Var3` and `Var4` may be `NAN` at the same time. I want to reshape the dataframe into

```
|   | Type | Var1 | Var2 |
|---|------|-----:|-----:|
| 0 |    A |  1.0 | 21.0 |
| 1 |    A |  2.0 | 22.0 |
| 2 |    A |  4.0 | 24.0 |
| 3 |    B |  3.0 | 23.0 |
| 4 |    B |  5.0 | 25.0 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try `concat` and select separately the columns, use `rename` on Var3 and Var4, then `dropna`, `sort_index` and `reset_index` to get the shape of the expected result.

```
res = (pd.concat([df[['Type', 'Var1','Var2']], 
                  df[['Type', 'Var3','Var4']]
                    .rename(columns={'Var3':'Var1', 'Var4':'Var2'})])
         .dropna(subset=['Var1','Var2'], how='all')
         .sort_index()
         .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
print(res)
  Type  Var1  Var2
0    A   1.0  21.0
1    A   2.0  22.0
2    A   4.0  24.0
3    B   3.0  23.0
4    B   5.0  25.0
```

Edit after comment: since you can have multiple times the repeated columns, you can try to do

```
#get all columns var1 and var2 independently, note that type must be the first one
l_var1 = df.columns[1:][0::2]
l_var2 = df.columns[1:][1::2]
res = (pd.concat([df[['Type', col_var1, col_var2]]
                    .rename(columns={col_var1:'Var1', col_var2:'Var2'})
                  for col_var1, col_var2 in zip(l_var1, l_var2)])
         .dropna(subset=['Var1','Var2'], how='all')
         .sort_index()
         .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer. I have an additional question. The real dataset has thousands of repeated columns. Is there an efficient way to construct the dataframe for the `concat`?

Comment: @WZhao probably if there is a logic in the name of the repeated columns? or if they are organised every X columns? can you give more details?

Comment: Sence the raw data is stored in the format of csv, the column name can be changed in the process of importing. Let us say the columns Var1 and Var2 are repeated for 20 times every two columns after the first column `Type`. Thus, there are 41 columns in total.

Comment: @WZhao see the edit, you can get list of columns or var1 and var2, then use a list comprehension :) Note that the final names Var1 and Var2 are hardcoded here so you can changed to any name you want (also change in dropna)

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple `concat()` does it.  `rename()` columns and `dropna()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type' : ['A', 'A', 'B'],
'Var1' : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
'Var2' : [21.0, 22.0, 23.0],
'Var3' : [np.nan, 4.0, 5.0],
'Var4' : [np.nan, 24.0, 25.0]
})

df = pd.concat([
    df.loc[:,['Type', 'Var1', 'Var2']],
    df.loc[:,['Type', 'Var3', 'Var4']].rename({"Var3":"Var1","Var4":"Var2"}, axis=1).dropna()
]).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df.to_string())
```

**output**

```
  Type  Var1  Var2
0    A   1.0  21.0
1    A   2.0  22.0
2    B   3.0  23.0
3    A   4.0  24.0
4    B   5.0  25.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like a hidden function `lreshape`, notice , this function not well documented!

```
df=pd.lreshape(df, {'Var1': ['Var1', 'Var3'], 'Var2': ['Var2', 'Var4']}).sort_values('Type')
df
Out[107]: 
  Type  Var1  Var2
0    A   1.0  21.0
1    A   2.0  22.0
3    A   4.0  24.0
2    B   3.0  23.0
4    B   5.0  25.0
```

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Type' : ['A', 'A', 'B'],
'Var1' : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
'Var2' : [21.0, 22.0, 23.0],
'Var3' : [np.nan, 4.0, 5.0],
'Var4' : [np.nan, 24.0, 25.0]
})

df1, df2 = df[['Type','Var1','Var2']], df[['Type','Var3','Var4']]
df2.rename(columns = {"Var3":"Var1","Var4":"Var2"}, inplace = True)
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df3.dropna(inplace = True)
df3.sort_values(by = 'Type', inplace = True)
print(df3.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
  Type  Var1  Var2
0    A   1.0  21.0
1    A   2.0  22.0
2    A   4.0  24.0
3    B   3.0  23.0
4    B   5.0  25.0
```